# How to send huge data (more than 512 Bytes) from the same characteristic of a GATT profile through Bluetooth Low energy?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to transfer more bytes of data from Android device using one characteristic. I am able to send 512 Bytes of data using Read Blob Request. But I need to transfer some Kilo Bytes of data. If I try to send more than 512 bytes, transfer is failing. Could some one please help me out.

Comment: how about splitting the data and sending it one by one?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for responding. I will have my characteristic pre loaded with data unsplitted and also Can I get it with only one read blob request? or Should I keep sending requests till I get whole data? Also, using blob request is limited to 512 Bytes only?

Comment: The maximum message size depends on your BLE device and your smartphone. You can't depend on the maximum size for all devices. Take a look at this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353764/7473793

Comment: Thank you. But, what if I don't want to use Notifications or Indications .I will be sending a read request from client(a computer) to my android.for the blob req, blob resp PDU will be sent back from android.

Comment: Does it have to be BLE? Bluetooth Classic is also available

Comment: Yes. It has to be BLE.

Comment: You could do it without notifications then, but you lose the flow control and information if something went wrong. Just send one message after another and finish with a specific message that tells you that it was the last

Comment: Thanks Michael, is it possible with single (read blob)request?

Comment: I don't believe so. Why do you need to use a single request only?