# Does Blob Request's offset goes beyond 512 in BLE?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

If I have a long attribute holding some 900 characters (900bytes)in android(server).When I try to read that through a Read Blob Request from computer(client), offset gets incremented by 22 starting from 0.(0,22,44...512) and Blob response will e sent accordingly. But, I could not see 534 even if the attribute(characteristic) still has data to be read. I want to understand 1)Is this the max limit in BLE and 2)how to send remaining data in one go from the same characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length of an attribute value is 512 bytes. That's why it's impossible to read beyond this offset. A proper Bluetooth stack should complain if you try to assign a larger value than what is allowed to a Characteristic, but Android.. well.. is Android...

So you can not read those "extra bytes" beyond offset 512, since they do not exist.

If you negotiate a larger MTU, you can read a larger part in one go. If you set it to 517, you can always read a maximum sized value using any GATT procedure in one single transaction.

Comment: Thank you Emil for clearing my confusion about offset. What would be your recommendation to transfer x Kilobytes of data from same characteristic without using Notifications. I read your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353764/7473793 .But, is there any other way?Please help me out

Comment: Is there anything wrong with notifications? Otherwise the only thing I can think of which is not deadly slow is to use L2CAP CoC, which there is support for in Android since version 10. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html and look at the functions whose names end with `L2capChannel`.

Comment: Reason I don't want to use notifications is, I want to get data response only upon request from client.

Comment: Hi Emil, hope you don't mind clearing this to me- I am not understanding: I could see in packet sniffer that my android sent 534 bytes when I have my characteristic with 600 bytes.( However client did receive, I need to change client code).

Comment: Sahana have you considered using a write characteristic to set the "chunk" of data that your read characteristic contains? A sort of basic fragmentation mechanism to break up your data.

Comment: If you want to get data only when requested, you can design it so that your notifications are sent whenever you receive some specific write command.